# How to read the AssemblyID of an Assembly DLL using the .Net Runtime Library for Delphi?

Tags: c#, .net, delphi, runtime

I need to create a function that allows me to read the AssemblyID directly from the Assembly DLL. I need this to register generically different assembly:

```
TClrAssembly.RegisterDLLAssembly(AssemblyGuid, AssemblyLocation, ltfileLocation);
```

Unfortunately my own solution does not work, because with certain DLLs the *GuidAttribute* is missing in the list of *CustomAttributesData*. For other DLLs I see this *GuidAttribute* but the content does not match the expected GUID.

This is my code:

```
function GUIDFromAssembly(AssemblyFileName: string): string;
var
  InspectedAssembly: _Assembly;
  GenericList: _GenericIList;
  GenericItems: _GenericICollection;
begin
  result := '';
  InspectedAssembly:= CoAssemblyHelper.CreateInstance.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(AssemblyFileName); 
  if not assigned(InspectedAssembly) then
    raise Exception.CreateFmt('Assembly %s not found', [AssemblyFileName]);

  GenericList := InspectedAssembly.GetCustomAttributesData;
  GenericItems := GenericList.AsGenericICollection;
  for c := 0 to GenericItems.Count - 1 do 
  begin
    s := GenericList.Item[c].ToString;
    Log(c.ToString + ': ' + s);
    if s.StartsWith('[System.Runtime.InteropServices.GuidAttribute("') then
      result := s.Substring(47, 36);
  end;
end;
```

What I also don't understand, why doesn't *_GenericIList* provide a *Length* property? Is my trick via *AsGenericICollection* correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only assemblies with ComVisible(true) are addressable by their GUID.

I have changed the way the assembly is loaded. I load it now directly via TClrAssembly.LoadFrom instead of indirectly via RegisterDLLAssembly so I don't need to know the GUID anymore.

In retrospect, this approach is much simpler and more direct.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use native Windows API methotds, if your app is windows only, for example: https://delphidabbler.com/articles/article-20

```
    function FileVersionGet( const sgFileName : string ) : string;
    var infoSize: DWORD;
    var verBuf:   pointer;
    var verSize:  UINT;
    var wnd:      UINT;
    var FixedFileInfo : PVSFixedFileInfo;
begin
  infoSize := GetFileVersioninfoSize(PChar(sgFileName), wnd);

  result := '';

  if infoSize <> 0 then
  begin
    GetMem(verBuf, infoSize);
    try
      if GetFileVersionInfo(PChar(sgFileName), wnd, infoSize, verBuf) then
      begin
        VerQueryValue(verBuf, '\', Pointer(FixedFileInfo), verSize);

        result := IntToStr(FixedFileInfo.dwFileVersionMS div $10000) + '.' +
                  IntToStr(FixedFileInfo.dwFileVersionMS and $0FFFF) + '.' +
                  IntToStr(FixedFileInfo.dwFileVersionLS div $10000) + '.' +
                  IntToStr(FixedFileInfo.dwFileVersionLS and $0FFFF);
      end;
    finally
      FreeMem(verBuf);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Sorry, but I am looking for the Assembly GUID and not the File Version Number.